# Issue with unittest.skipif()

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using unit test framework to run some tests in a class. I also have a helper function called connected_emulators.
I want to skip test_get_emulator_device if the conditions is True which is the case.

My problem is I'm getting this message when running the tests :

```
def connected_emulators(self):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['adb', '-e', 'get-serialno'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
    return True
@unittest.skipIf(not(self.connected_emulators()), 'Expected failure, no 
emulators connected')  
def test_get_emulator_device(self):
    device = get_emulator_device()
    self.assertIsInstance(device, AndroidDevice)
```

OUTPUT :
    @unittest.skipIf(not(self.connected_emulators()), 'Expected failure, no emulators connected') NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters to the `@unittest.skipIf` decorator are evaluated when the module is loaded because the decorator is being applied when the method is defined (at module load time). At that point in time, there is no instance of your test class so "self" has no meaning. "self" only has meaning *within* a classes method.

You should just move the `connected_emulators` method out as a function at the global scope so that you can call it without requiring an instance of your test class. I don't see any reason why it has to be a method of your class, based on the code you posted.

```
def connected_emulators():
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['adb', '-e', 'get-serialno'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
    return True

class MyTestClass:
    @unittest.skipIf(not(connected_emulators()), 'Expected failure, no emulators connected')  
    def test_get_emulator_device(self):
        device = get_emulator_device()
        self.assertIsInstance(device, AndroidDevice)
```